# While running grunt watch - it throws warning while running express server task and aborts

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

While running grunt watch - it throws warning while running express server task and aborts.

The warnings are as below:

```
    Running "express-server:devServer" (express-server) task
    Warning: Object function createServer() {
      function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
      merge(app, proto);
      merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
      app.route = '/';
      app.stack = [];
      return app;
    } has no method 'static' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and the solution was downgrading grunt-contrib-connect to version 0.10.1

So edit your package.json:

```
"grunt-contrib-connect": "0.10.1",
```

and then run

```
npm update
```

in your project directory.

I think they changed middleware function parameters in v11. I use Gruntfile.js from AngularJS generator v0.12.1